# Safari browser not working on Click event to show loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have to show loading image on `Cancel` button click as shown below.It seems working fine on FF,Chrome but in Safari its not working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="loading" id="overlay">
    <div id="loading_message"></div>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="next_action" id="cancel" formnovalidate value="Cancel">
```

**JS**

```
function ShowDialog(){
  $("#loading_message").html('Please Wait');
  $("#loading_message").css('left','52%');
  $('#overlay').show();    
}
$( document ).on( "click",'input#cancel',function(event) {
        ShowDialog();
});
```

Another thing to add that if I put `alert` on `Click` event then It displays alert and then loading image will display as below but without it is not working.

```
$( document ).on( "click",'input#cancel',function(event) {
        alert('Hello');
        ShowDialog();
});
```

I have also try with `setTimeout` function for `ShowDialog()` to pause and show message but its not working.
Can you please advise me? 
Thanks for your time.

Update
I am using Jquery v1.7.2.

Comment: `id` is unique, you can use `#cancel` instead of `input#cancel`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? When I recreate this with http://jsfiddle.net/FW9Tx/ and run chrome as Safari 5.0.4 it works shows the alert and the "Please Wait" message...

Comment: @PazcaldeJonge Loading image is not displayed in safari for clicking on Cancel button

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(document).on('click','input#cancel')` is a lot of elements to read an interaction so to speak. If you're not using a jQuery version less than 1.5 I think it is you can use `.click` as an eventHandler. Your selector could use a bit of simplifying too. A jQuery select works like this `$('element of interest','within this element')` but you can build on these greatly. For instance what you've written can also be written as `$('input#cancel',document)`. But the document isn't required to be looked in because the select will already look within the document.

Another thing I must add. jQuery can only 'run' once the document is loaded. So a `document.ready` function is required to 'check' that the document has loaded. Here's a better solution for your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){//notice the ready function
    $('input#cancel').click(function(event){
        //the element in the selector that initiated the function is now 'this' used as $(this)
        event.preventDefault();//instead, if desired, use return false; to prevent default and propagination
        alert('hello');
        showDialog();
        return true;//to submit the form.
    });
});
```

functions that aren't called by jQuery listeners don't necessarily need to be within the `document.ready` function. So we can have these else where within the document and jQuery selectors can still be used.

```
function showDialog(){
    $("#loading_message").html('Please Wait');
    $("#loading_message").css('left','52%');
    $('#overlay').show();
}
```

This should help with your safari issue hopefully.